# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files jupytor notebook?

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, imagenet

I have dataset of image-net. i want to perform different operation on them. but when i iterate through loop i get error of too many open file.
i make new folder and keep four images on that folder. Code run successfully but its not working in all dataset.
my code is

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib

import cv2
import statistics
import numpy as np
import pandas
import numpy

import statistics
import glob

colorIm = []
for filename in glob.glob(r'G:/Zakia/ADL_Codes/Image_Set/*.JPEG'):
   img = Image.open(filename)
   colorIm.append(img)
greyIm = [img.convert('L') for img in colorIm]
greyIm = [np.array(img) for img in greyIm]
print ("number_of_grayscale_images:",len(greyIm))
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for Image.open. It will say that this function keeps the file open and does not read anything unless you actually do something with the file. I recommend doing the processing in the same loop and then closing the file before moving to the next image.

Comment: how to closing the file